# C: Checking an array contains only numbers in the range 0-7

Tags: c, arrays, validation, numeric

I'm having difficulty ensuring an array is filled with only numbers in the range 0-7.
When I fill the array with numbers outside the range eg. 0 0 0 8 the error message displays. However if the user enters a letter my program crashes.

```
 int array[4] = {0};  

 scanf("%d %d %d %d", &array[0], &array[1], &array[2], &array[3]);

 for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(array[i]) && array[i]<8 && array[i]>=0)
        {
             // continue program
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid entry.");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One less test (than haccks' solution):

```
if (array[i] & ~7) {
    invalid_input();
} else {
    /* valid input */
}
```

If you still have problems, then the problem may lie elsewhere ?..

Comment: Very nice xtof pernod!

Comment: Thanks Valter =) You know, it's just basic bits handling, as 7 is one less than a power of 2, it can be  used for masking..

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the isdigit() is used for testing whether a character is a digit and takes character typecasted into integer as an argument and you are passing an integer. When you pass it an integer 0 it is actually 0 in decimal but when you pass it character '0' it is 48 in decimal.Since '0' in ascii is 48 in decimal, so to convert from ascii to integer just subtract 48 from the input character before testing it for range (between 0 and 8)

```
char array[4] = {0};
int i=0;
scanf("%c %c %c %c", &array[0], &array[1], &array[2], &array[3]);
for(i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    if(isdigit(array[i]) && (array[i]-48) <= 7 && (array[i]-48) >= 0)
    {
         printf(" continue program");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Invalid entry.");
        break;
    }
}
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(array[i] >= 0 && array[i] < 8 ) {...}
```

No need to check for `isdigit` as it works for `char`s not for `int`s or `float`.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's probably the scanf() function barfing on non-integer input. The
   error message should give some hint if that's the case.
2. You've read the input as a number already, so isdigit() is likely
   going to be false (0). It expects a single *character* input.
3. `for(int i` looks more like C++ than C. Your compiler might be
   actually compiling in C++ mode.
4. Note that if you enter an unsigned integer *starting with a 0* and
   containing only the digits 0 through 7, that C is likely to
   interpret that as an *octal* number. If you enter something like
   `01234` it may well be read in as something other than decimal 1234.

Comment: `scanf("%d", ...)` reads decimal numbers, ignores leading zeros and does not treat them as special and does not know about the `0x` prefix. ( `strtod` reads C-style numbers when the base is 0, and only decimals when the base is 10.) Also, your octal theory does not explain the OP's problem. In C99, declaration of loop variables in `for` is allowed.

Comment: I wasn't talking about 0x... I was talking about 0... I was just noting for their benefit that they could possibly get into trouble (many people have) by unwittingly entering an octal value. To make it bulletproof, you'd probably have to read as strings and feed the substrings to strtold() or something.

Comment: The convention to treat numbers with a leading zero as octals is a potential pitfall, I agree, but `scanf("%d")` does not use that convention. My mentioning of `0x` was just to back up that fact: If it knew about `0` for octal, it would probably also know about `0x`. Anyway, I think the OP's problem is in the parts of the code he hasn't shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can just search the elements in the array and verify that they are between 0 and 7.

```
if(array[i]>=0 &&array[i]<=7)
{ 
    continue program
}
else
. . .
```